# Typescript Nested Objects / Json

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm new to programming and JavaScript, i tried creating an interface for a code challenge, but i keep getting this error message:

```
Type '{ 1100: { albumTitle: string; artist: string; tracks: string[]; }; 2468: { albumTitle: string; artist: string; tracks: string[]; }; 1245: { artist: string; tracks: never[]; }; 5439: { albumTitle: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'collectionInfo'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and '1100' does not exist in type 'collectionInfo'.ts(2322)
```

Please i need your suggestions on how to resolve this or how to create a typescript interface that will eliminate this error message.

```
This my typescript interface attempt:

interface collectionInfo {
        id : {
            albumTitle: string | number |;
            artist: string | number |;
            tracks: string[] | number[] | null; 
        }
}

const recordCollection: collectionInfo = {
    1100: {
      albumTitle: "Prisoner",
      artist: "Lucky Dube",
      tracks: ["Prisoner", "Don\'t Cry"],
    },
```

Comment: Replace `id` with an index signature - `[id: number]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options.

First is to use [id: number] like this:

```js
interface collectionInfo {
  [id: number] : {
    albumTitle: string | number | null;
    artist: string | number | null;
    tracks: string[] | number[] | null; 
  }
}

const recordCollection: collectionInfo = {
  1100: {
    albumTitle: "Prisoner",
    artist: "Lucky Dube",
    tracks: ["Prisoner", "Don\'t Cry"],
  }
}
```

And the second way is to add id to properties and then use an array instead like this:

```js
interface collectionInfo {
  id: number;
  albumTitle: string | number | null;
  artist: string | number | null;
  tracks: string[] | number[] | null;
}

const recordCollection: collectionInfo[] = [
  {
    id: 1100,
    albumTitle: "Prisoner",
    artist: "Lucky Dube",
    tracks: ["Prisoner", "Don\'t Cry"],
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
interface CollectionInfo {
   [id: number]: {
      albumTitle: string | number;
      artist: string | number;
      tracks: string[] | number[] | null; 
   }
}
```

try refactoring your interface

```
interface CollectionInfo {
   id: number;
   albumTitle: string; // I recommend sticking to one type only
   artist: string | number;
   tracks?: string[] | number[]; // if you are trying to add optional property, use ? to make it optional
}

const recordCollection: CollectionInfo = {
   id: 1100,
   albumTitle: "Prisoner",
   artist: "Lucky Dube",
   tracks: ["Prisoner", "Don't Cry"]
}

// Usage
console.log(recordCollection.id); // 1100
console.log(recordCollection.albumTitle); // Prisoner
```

Answer (score 0):

`collectionInfo` is structured in a way that implies that an instance of this type would be an object containing a single attribute, `id`, that itself represents an object contains some other attributes.

You need to modify your type definition to allow the object to contain somewhat of a map. These two solutions are equivalent, though I would prefer the second one:

```js
interface CollectionsInfo {
  [id: number]: {
    albumTitle: string | number;
    artist: string | number;
    tracks: string[] | number[] | null; 
  }
}
```

```js
interface CollectionInfo {
  albumTitle: string | number;
  artist: string | number;
  tracks: string[] | number[] | null;
}

type CollectionsInfo = Record<number, CollectionInfo>;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues I can notice:

1. there are trailing pipes `|` in the interface definition. Although this might not exactly be the problem.
2. The `recordCollection` is using `1100` in the place of `id` which is defined in the interface `collectionInfo`.

Below is how I think it should look:

```js
interface collectionInfo {
        id : {
            albumTitle: string | number;
            artist: string | number;
            tracks: string[] | number[] | null; 
        }
}
const recordCollection: collectionInfo = {
  id: {
      albumTitle: "Prisoner",
      artist: "Lucky Dube",
      tracks: ["Prisoner", "Don\'t Cry"],
    },
}
```

Alternatively, if the id must be a number, then you could try this:

```js
interface collectionInfo {
        [key: number] : {
            albumTitle: string | number;
            artist: string | number;
            tracks: string[] | number[] | null; 
        }
}
const recordCollection: collectionInfo = {
  1100: {
      albumTitle: "Prisoner",
      artist: "Lucky Dube",
      tracks: ["Prisoner", "Don\'t Cry"],
    },
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
interface collectionInfo {
        [id: number] : {
            albumTitle: string | number ;
            artist: string | number ;
            tracks: string[] | number[] | null; 
        }
     }
```